# Selected tabs in the reopen queue are nearly impossible to see using dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design, dark-mode

The "Question (revised)", "Revision", or "Duplicate" tabs in the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/) on questions that have them are nearly impossible to see when they're selected in dark mode.

[image]

Hovering over it gives it the necessary contrast to be read, though it doesn't quite fit and seems like an unintentional highlight that's meant for light mode.

[image]

Comment: This is probably reported already in the big composite list of issues with Dark Mode. It's the Dark Mode announcement Q&A here on MSO. But yes, it's a bit mind boggling that such basic issues haven't been fixed yet.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't see this *exact* issue, though there were a few in the same realm. I might not have looked hard enough of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still chipping away at those old tab components. Fixed! Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Still a few cases of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402958/unable-to-read-user-tab-on-tag-info-page-when-using-dark-mode