# Unable to read "User" tab on tag info page when using dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

The text on the "users" tab of the ["Tag Info" (e.g. python)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) page is unreadable in Dark Mode.
Also, when hovering the mouse, it is displayed in the color of the Light Mode.

[image]

[image]

Related:
[Selected tabs in the reopen queue are nearly impossible to see using dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399815)

Comment: This is already well-known. These are legacy tab components that will get replaced by modern Stacks components later. See [Dark Mode Beta - help us root out low-contrast and un-converted bits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4642212).

Comment: @user4642212: Are you suggesting to close this question? With that target (link)?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. There have been several of these cases ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398799), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399815), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401966)), but they're being reported and fixed independently. As user4642212 said, it's because the legacy tab component doesn't properly support Dark Mode. The fix is for a developer to convert the tab component to the new Stacks-styled component, which does support the Dark Mode. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @CodyGray - This one still hasn't been fixed. Also, I found the same issue on the [Events page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events?tab=past)... should I open another Question for that? (This page isa lot worse in dark mode than just the tabs at the top - the whole page has wonky shades of gray for outlines and text.)

Comment: Does anyone know if the issue is going to be addressed anytime soon? Not a big deal, of course, but still is annoying to look at every time when opening the tag info page.

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this issue and fixed a number of other similar issues with the same outdated component across various pages on the site in the process. Thanks for the report. The fix will be merged in today or tomorrow.