# Active link in navbar of moderator tools in darkmode has very low contrast

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode

The label of the active tab on the navbar in darkmode in some of the moderator tools has very low contrast and is difficult to read. While the hover active is quite bright compared to other darkmode hovers.

This appears to be the same styling mentioned in [Unable to read "User" tab on tag info page when using dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402958/unable-to-read-user-tab-on-tag-info-page-when-using-dark-mode), however, that question appears to have been marked resolved on June 2nd, 2021 and I noticed the styles below today July 25th, 2021.

---

The css selectors seem to be:

- `#tabs a.youarehere, .tabs a.youarehere`
- `#tabs a.youarehere:hover, .tabs a.youarehere:hover`

For completeness, this appears on the navbars of the following tools:

1. Protected Questions https://stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions
2. Suggested Edits https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits
3. Question Close Stats https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats

Active Tab:

[image: active tab]

Hover Active Tab:

[image: hover active tab]

4. Only the Migrated tab in tools (https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=today) has this styling:

[image: migrated tab]

While all others (Stats, Close, and Delete) appear as:

[image: stats tab]

---

1. Can the contrast be increased so the text is more easily readable?
2. Is it the expected behaviour that the Migrated Tab use a different navbar than Stats, Close and Delete?

Comment: Has that changed recently or was this a long standing issue?

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402958/unable-to-read-user-tab-on-tag-info-page-when-using-dark-mode

Comment: They seem to be twiddling with color scheme parameters: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367761/did-the-color-contrast-of-closed-question-box-just-change  so this might be a result of that and maybe a corner casse that didn't get their attention yet.

Comment: I noticed it today. You are correct that is 100% the same behaviour for sure. Although that thread seems to say it was resolved, and these are from today. What would you suggest I do with this question?

Comment: I would edit to add the tag  bug and mention the other question is about a different view and that this popped up today after the other bug was called resolved, making this a new occurrence of a similar but not duplicate issue.